# Are Javascript objects always unique

Tags: javascript

If I do:

```
const o1 = {};
const o2 = {};
```

is it guaranteed that `o1===o2` is false?

Comment: The alternative would be that `o1.foo = 123` would also alter `o2`, which someone would have noticed by now.

Comment: Yes, it's guaranteed. Both variables point to a different memory location. Since comparison on objects is based on whether both objects refer to the same memory location, the code you've shown can never be `true`.